# injecting jetty spring servlet with guice(or changing it so I can inject it)

Tags: java, spring, servlets, jersey, jetty

I cloned servlet:
https://github.com/eHarmony/vw-webservice . I want to start this servlet from my jetty code. I am using guice to add classes to jetty. It looks like I need to move applicationContext so it works as a jar, not war . I don't have experience with jetty or spring. I would love to hear what you think about it.

GuiceConfig.java

```
public class GuiceConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener
{
    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector()
    {
        return Guice.createInjector(new JerseyServletModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configureServlets() {    
                bind(ClassThatProcessRequest.class);

                bind(InjecteeInterface.class).to(Injectee.class);
                serve("/*").with(GuiceContainer.class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and main.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        ServletContextHandler root = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/", ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);

        root.addEventListener(new GuiceConfig());
        root.addFilter(GuiceFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));
        root.addServlet(EmptyServlet.class, "/*");

        server.start();
    }
}
```

When I start server I get

```
com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

No implementation for com.eharmony.matching.vw.webservice.core.exampleprocessor.ExampleProcessorFactory was bound.
```

here is applicationContext.xml and web.xml
https://github.com/eHarmony/vw-webservice/blob/master/vw-webservice-jersey/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml

https://github.com/eHarmony/vw-webservice/blob/master/vw-webservice-jersey/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

Comment: Is there a reason you are attempting to combine Guice and Spring in the same project?  That seems strange.  As both do the same thing, and can (in some cases) conflict with each other.  It would probably be more sane to pick one, Guice *or* Spring.

Comment: I want to pass big object as a singleton(so it's not created during each request) and I don't really know how to do this with spring in web servlet